# Clear Network Logs in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to read logs from network tab in chrome browser for each action in the web page. Since there are no unique values to identify the network logs, I need to clear the network logs after every event. I have tried `console.clear` to clear the logs, but its not working. Please let me know how it can be done

```js
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String script = "console.clear();";
js.executeScript(script);
```

Comment: I have modified the question, Java has nothing to do with JavaScipt.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this by executing JavaScript in the console. You'd need intercept the Chrome window and execute `Ctrl + E` twice (Windows) or `Command + E` twice (Mac).

**The above is not achievable using Client-side JavaScript.**

`Ctrl/Command + E` shortcut stops the network tab recording and doing it the second time cleans the log and starts recording again, **there's no shortcut to clean the log or do it from the console.**